# Как проверить переменную: число это или нет?

Tags: php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/id".и тут должно быть написано любое число."") {
   выводим результат
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**[`is_int()`](http://www.php.su/functions/?is-int)** + **[`is_float()`](http://www.php.su/functions/?is-float)**:

```
$a = 1.0;
if(is_int($a) || is_float($a))
{
   //выводим результат;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте is_numeric()  
А если не сложно и можно, выложите пожалуйста код регулярки, может кому будет нужно тоже